# fwrite to a document and fgets from it

Tags: php

**Info:** I am trying to read and write to a file at the same time, but if i have `r+` it will only write and if i only have `r` it will only read, but i need it do both so it can get the info into the document and the info out of it to a cmd window.

**Question:** Is there i way i can do this and that both will work?

```
$outputMXA = shell_exec($commandMXA);
$fhMXA = fopen('MXA.txt','r+');
fwrite($fhMXA,$outputMXA);

$MXA = fgets($fhMXA);
```

Comment: `r+` is read/write both. Or can use `x+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$outputMXA = shell_exec($commandMXA);
$fhMXA = fopen('MXA.txt','rw');
fwrite($fhMXA,$outputMXA);

$MXA = fgets($fhMXA);
fclose($fhMXA);
```

Edit:

Or you must separate both actions :

```
$outputMXA = shell_exec($commandMXA);
$fhMXA = fopen('MXA.txt','w+');
fwrite($fhMXA,$outputMXA);
fclose($fhMXA);

$fhMXA = fopen('MXA.txt','r+');
$MXA = fgets($fhMXA);
fclose($fhMXA);
```